Database structure many-to-many
I am having trouble with structuring my database. I want to have a record of a Book, with its Chapters and PageNotes.
I need every user to have their own copy of this Book/Chapters/PageNotes so they can add their own user-specific entries like isCompleted to track what chapter/page they are on etc.
This is what I have so far, it's becoming fairly complicated, any help appreciated!
 public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
 public DbSet<PageNotes> PageNotes { get; set; }

 public DbSet<UserBookEntry> UserBookEntries { get; set; }     // So each user can have their own record of a book that they can modify
 public DbSet<UserChapterEntry> UserChapterEntries { get; set; }     // So each user can have their own record of a chapter that they can modify
 public DbSet<UserPageNoteEntry> UserPageNoteEntries { get; set; }     // So each user can have their own record of a page note that they can modify

My classes:
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Price { get; set; } = decimal.Zero;

    public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; } = new List<Chapter>();

}

public class Chapter
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<PageNote>? PageNotes { get; set; } = new List<Note>();

    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public class PageNote
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [ForeignKey("ChapterId")]
    public string ChapterId { get; set; }
    public Chapter Chapter { get; set; }
}

public class UserBookEnty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BooksId")]
    public string BooksId { get; set; }

    // Any user-specific properties
    public bool BookOwned { get; set; } = false;
}

public class UserChapterEntry
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BooksId")]
    public string BooksId { get; set; }
    
    // Any User-Specific chapter properties
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; } = false;
}

public class UserPageNoteEntry
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChapterId")]
    public string ChapterId { get; set; }

    // Any user-specific chapter properties
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; } = false;
}

How would I structure this properly in Entity Framework Core? I think I am missing some parts.

What's the actual problem here? You say that you want to do something and this is how you're doing it. OK, so what's the problem. You say that you think that you're missing some parts. What do you think is missing and why? It's not for us to peruse your code and see if we can see an y issue that needs fixing. It's for you to tell us what the issue is.

If you're going to use a GUID, why not actually use a Guid rather than converting it to a string?

The Guid type is more compact than string, and has its advantages, but I am always having to convert it to the string value to use it in my code anyway.

@ScottishSmile no you don't and shouldn't. This is no different than dates or numbers. You should keep it as a Guid and only convert it to string when you need to display it or write it to a file. Using a GUID as a database key has severe disadvantages though and generating it on the client means you can't use .Update to update or add detached entities any more

My code above is not complete, I have "hacked" it together from various sources but it doesn't even actually tie into the  Db yet. Does it need a  table as well?

EF deals with entities, not tables. It returns application objects, not rows. Since EF Core 7 at least you don't need a bridge entity (but you do need the many-to-many table). EF Core will either generate it or use an existing one that meets naming conventions. That's explained in the Many-to-Many relations docs. The examples show you don't need a BlogPosts entity, that the table will be created automatically if you use migrations, how to handle modifications, and how to use a table explicitly if you have to.
